# UWP TabView change tab programatically

Tags: c++, uwp, tabview

How can I change TabView's tab programatically? For example user have 2'nd tab opened and I want to change tab to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you have to do it as following:

```
int index = 1;
if (tabcontrol->TabItems->Size > index)
{
    tabcontrol->SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view)

You can do it by the following:

```
// Only select the tab if it is in the list
if (tabToSelect < TabRoot.TabItems.Count)
{
    TabRoot.SelectedIndex = tabToSelect;
}
```